# How to write down this symbol?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

[image]

I tried to use different command I know. But none of them are satisfactory.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: For such questions, https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is a great tool.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Excellent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, load the [mathrsfs](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs) package, which provides a heavily-sloped set of "formal script" letters for use in math mode, in the preamble. Then, write `\mathscr{S}` (in math mode) in the body of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{S}$
\end{document}
```